# Error in is.constant(y) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r, plm

I have a sample file that I am using to forecast as a panel series. 
 The steps followed are

```
library(plm)
library(Formula)
library(forecast)
library(timeDate)
library(zoo)

df1 <- read.csv("full panel Test Input.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
pdf1 <- plm.data(df1,index=c("state","time"))
fmodel1 <- plm(M4~M1+M2+M3,data=pdf1,model="within")
fcast <- forecast(fmodel1,data=pdf1)
```

I get the error stated in the subject exactly at step nine. The process and the data is fine since we have checked it in stata.

Any help is appreciated.

```
M1  M2  M3  M4  state   time
466 63  14  10  AZ  2013w31
0   63  0   0   AZ  2013w32
480 63  77  270 AZ  2013w33
0   63  0   0   AZ  2013w34
10  0   742 40  AZ  2013w35
0   0   0   0   AZ  2013w36
0   0   210 10  AZ  2013w37
1049    28  168 30  AZ  2013w38
1148    35  203 20  AZ  2013w39
5130    182 21  10  AZ  2013w40
8667    427 0   10  AZ  2013w41
460000  10731   14  20  AZ  2013w42
1000000 27608   0   120 AZ  2013w43
0   27608   0   0   AZ  2013w44
18494   1344    7   30  AZ  2013w45
15775   1176    21  10  AZ  2013w46
15516   1197    0   40  AZ  2013w47
0   1197    0   0   AZ  2013w48
0   1197    0   0   AZ  2013w49
11280   700 0   30  AZ  2013w50
6320    336 14  50  AZ  2013w51
765 35  0   20  AZ  2013w52
230 0   0   10  AZ  2014w1
0   0   0   0   NJ  2013w31
0   0   0   0   NJ  2013w32
6   0   0   10  NJ  2013w33
```

Comment: I suspect the issue is that `forecast` is not set up to handle `plm` models.

Comment: Hi Joran, If forecast is not set up to handle plm models then which package should we be using ?